# Tcp Server Only Allowing 1 Client

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Server.cs - https://hastebin.com/enajinewij.cs

Client.cs - https://hastebin.com/iriperubur.cs

I have tried both running the Client on another PC and running it on one PC, but both result in the Client not being able to receive or send any messages.

I CANT portforward. I am using Hamachi for the IP Address. Both client and server are connected to my Network and are using the Hamachi IP Address. I am using PDA Net to connect to the internet from my PC.

The Server does not see them connect at all. Nor does the Server get any messages from them. Currently only the Server can send messages, and only it can get them.

I am not getting ANY errors at all, so I am not sure how I should handle solving this issue as it's my first time working with networking.

Comment: Both of your links to hastebin are the source for `class Client` but that's OK because you should really post the code here anyway.  In order to get good answers it's best to ask a good question and stack overflow provides [this article: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to help you get started.

Comment: I can't put the code here because it's over 200 lines total.
That would be way to big. Also I have no clue where the problem begins and where it ends.

I read the information about asking a question and I feel like this is the best way to provide code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first you create a `TcpListener` and you call `StartLis()` that does `BeginAcceptTcpClient`. However in `AcceptTCPClient` you create a *new* `TcpListener` and `BeginAcceptTcpClient` is not called.

You don't have to create a new listener for each connection, but you do have to call `BeginAcceptTcpclient` again:

```
private void AcceptTCPClient(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    TcpListener Lis = (TcpListener)ar.AsyncState;

    Clients.Add(new ServerClient(Lis.EndAcceptTcpClient(ar)));

    StartLis(); // this will call BeginAcceptTcpClient again
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Worked like a charm an provided me with enough information to hopefully prevent me from doing it again :D